# 'Please wait' screen between pages in C# ASP.NET. Best practice?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a gridview with some imagebuttons, each of which kicks off a report page for that item.  The report take 10-15 seconds to run, so I'd like a popup 'Generating report, please wait' type thing.  I can think of a few ways but would like the opinion of those more experienced than I.  The options I was considering:

a) link my imagebutton to an intermediate page that says 'please wait', and then refer it onto the report page from there.  Seems a bit clunky
b) Investigate using jquery or similar.  I have telerik controls, they have a few things but it isn't clear if any are suitable.
c) Define some kind of CSS layer with a please wait warning on it, and make it visible as part of the button's onclick event
d) Look into jquery or similar

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use Div with transparency, and its pretty cool and simple. Give it a try.

```
 <div id="ModalPopup" style="visibility: hidden;">
  <div style="position: fixed; width: 100%; height: 100%; z-index: 10002; background-color: Gray;
    filter: alpha(opacity=70); opacity: 0.7;">
    &nbsp;
  </div>
  <table style="position: fixed; width: 100%; height: 100%; z-index: 10003;">
    <tr>
      <td align="center" valign="middle">
        <div style="color: Black; font-weight: bolder; background-color: White; padding: 15px;
          width: 200px;">
          <asp:Image ID="Image3" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/progress.gif" />
          Procesando....
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  </div>
```

To display the div, use this JavaScript:

document.getElementById('ModalPopup').style.visibility = 'visible';

Comment: Thanks mate.  I placed it on the 'first' form where my buttons are but it is visible from the start.  How do you make it invisible and then make it appear once the user clicks a button?  I'm no JS guy... :)

Comment: Add this style yo the main div Style="display: none"
Then on your buton add onClientClick="document.getElementById['ModalPopup'].style.visibility='visible'"

Comment: Hi Alej, I have tried a number of variants of this and no luck thus far! No room to paste the code either unfortunately.  I've put a button with that onclientclick event but it just posts back without making the div visible.  If you happen to have an .aspx file that shows it in action, if you could flick it to foley.mark@gmail.com that would be excellent.  cheers mate

Comment: This solution was the easiest one I found, so thanks!  One thing to note, if you are using ASP.NET to hide and show the div, be sure to add runat="server" into the main ModualPopup tag.

Answer (score 1):

I have the exact same problem before but I found the AJAX Server Control UpdateProgress very useful. Here's a link to [UpdateProgress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398821.aspx) Control.

Comment: Thanks for that - this seems to be for partial page updates?  In the present case I'm moving from one page to a whole other one.  Not sure if it works in this case?

Answer (score 0):

you can have an `<iframe>` on the page, of which its `style` is set to `display:none`. a button (which you will use to execute an action) will perform a javascript function that will set the style of the `<iframe>` to `display:block` on click.

Answer (score 0):

please wait on page load in js can be used in any language give a try

1. in body place this code

```
  <body>
    <div id='loadingmsg' style='display: none;'></div>
    <div id='loadingover' style='display: none;'></div>
  </body>
```

2. in css

```
          #loadingmsg {
    width:100%;
height:100%;
position:fixed;
z-index:9999;
background:url("assets/img/loaders/load10.gif") no-repeat center center rgba(255,255,255,0);
      }
      #loadingover {
      background: #23351f;
      z-index: 99;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=80)";
      filter: alpha(opacity=80);
      -moz-opacity: 0.8;
      -khtml-opacity: 0.8;
      opacity: 0.8;
    }
```

3. js

```
   <script>
       document.onreadystatechange = function () {
           var state = document.readyState
           if (state == 'interactive') {
               showLoading();
           }
           else if (state == 'complete') {
              
                   hideLoading();
              
           }
       }

      
        function showLoading() {
            document.getElementById('loadingmsg').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('loadingover').style.display = 'block';
        }
        function hideLoading() {
            document.getElementById('loadingmsg').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('loadingover').style.display = 'none';
        }
    </script>
```